# <article> или role="article"

Tags: html, html5

С появлением html5 у меня регулярно возникает много вопросов. И в сабже один из них.

Тег `<article>` появился в html5 и судя по информации с разных источников применяется для обозначения раздела страницы, содержащего завершенную, независимую композицию

В то же время появился и семантический атрибут `role`, который так же может иметь значение `"article"`, имеющее тот же самый смысл, что и тег `article`.

Зачем было вводить `role` со значением "article", если для этого был введен соответствующий тег?

Если смысл был, то какая между ними разница и в каком случае предпочтительнее использовать тег, и в каком атрибут?

С уважением

Comment: если не ошибаюсь html5 появился или родился в 2014 году ...а role наиболее четко указывает семантическое предназначение блока...

Comment: @MaximLensky HTML5 появился максимум [в 2008 году](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080122/) (и уже в 2009 году свежевышедший Internet Explorer 8 поддерживал парочку новых возможностей из HTML5)

Comment: @andreymal я ни спец по html5 но wiki говорит что html5 повился в 2014 году а до этого было html4

Comment: у тебя все еще вопросы...

Comment: @MaximLensky , ну так а в чем разница между `role="article"`и `<article>`? `<article>` же тоже явно указывает предназначение. Когда предпочтительнее использовать что из этого?

Comment: @Данил, ну так-то да. html5 давно появился, а вопросы остаются